# Relationship between wearing a kippa and reciting a blessing

Tags: halacha, blessing, shemos-sacred-names, kippa-yarmulka

Before I started wearing a Kippa all the time, the people around me and I had the reflex to cover our head when saying the name of G-d or when reciting anything holy.

Since the mitzvah is to wear it at all times, then why would it matter more while reciting a blessing? Is there an additional ordinance to wear it while reciting Hashem?

If my Kippa fell and I recited a blessing without a kippa, would it matter more than if I walked around without one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Orach Chaim 91:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=244) - The Beis Yosef says that Yesh Omrim that you are not allowed to say Hashem's name with your head uncovered.

Answer (score 7):

The *Mishna Berurah* in *siman* 25 *s"k* 27 says that when putting on the *Tefilah Shel Rosh*, one should be careful that his head is covered before making the beracha. He gives the source as the *Pri Megadim*.

Comment: mocdeg, welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for this very relevant source! Please consider registering [your account](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1261/mocdeg), which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 0):

בס"ד
Taken from [here](http://www.dinonline.org/2013/08/11/berachah-recited-without-kippah/)

Although one should be careful to make all berachos with a head-covering (kippah), if a berachah is recited without covering one’s head the berachah is valid, and is not repeated.

The same applies for all prayers.

Best wishes.

Sources:
Even (some of) those authorities who write that there is no obligation to wear a kippah all the time, rule that one must do so when reciting a berachah (Kol Bo 11; Or Zarua 2:43; Tur, Orach Chaim 8; Rabbeinu Yerucham; Taz 8:3).

One must therefore be careful to cover one’s head when making a berachah (see also Orach Chaim 91:4, and Mishnah Berurah 91:10).

However, there is no question that a berachah recited without a head-covering remains valid, and cannot be repeated.