# May a man learn Torah without a Kippah?

Tags: halacha, minhag, torah-study, kippa-yarmulka

Is it permissible for a man to learn Torah without a Kippah?

Let's say that he can't wear a Kippah at work, or he lives someplace where it is dangerous to outwardly display signs of being Jewish, yet, for whatever reason, picking up a Sefer, or logging on to Mi Yodeya, would go unnoticed.  Would this be ok to do?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14347/759

Comment: Denmark? [15 chr]

Comment: why do you think it might be a problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> אף-על-פי שבודאי שאין ללמוד תורה בגילוי ראש, מכל מקום אין זה מעיקר הדין, אך יש להזהר בזה מאד, ואפי' כשלומד לבד בחדרו. [שו''ת יביע אומר ח''ו חאו''ח סי' טו סק''ז]‏

Meikar Hadin (according to the letter of the law) one isn't obligated to learn with a head covering: nevertheless, one should certainly wear a head covering while learning (even alone in his room).

> "Even though one should certainly not learn Torah without a head
>   covering, nevertheless this isn't from the letter of the law. However,
>   one should be very meticulous with this even in his own room."