# Is a gentile required to wear a kippah while studying Torah?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, torah-study, kippa-yarmulka

A Jew must not walk around with his head non-covered  (Shu"A Orach Chayim 2,6 " ולא ילך ארבע אמות בגילוי הראש מפני כבוד השכינה).

Is a gentile required to cover his head while studying Torah? If a gentile studies Torah without his head covered, is he violating a rabbinical commandment?

Comment: Goyim don’t have to follow any mitzvos except for b’nei Noach. I assume wearing a kippah while learning is included in this rule.

Comment: Being very specific, here ... It says that you can't walk 4 amot without head covering. How does that equate to sitting at a table to study Torah? Perhaps, edit that into the question. I think it's useful info for this question.

Comment: Do you have any source that covering one's head is in any way obligated by learning Torah?

Comment: First off, being that presumably most follow the Taz in respect why we wear a kippa "v'lo s'laychu" (don't go after the goyim..etc) and therefore one would cover his head. A Goy, does not by any means fall into this category.

Comment: @Moshe We wear kippah as a sign of respect to and acknowledgment of the Divine Presence

Comment: @chortkov2 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22800/may-a-man-learn-torah-without-a-kippah

Comment: First off you have to understand what's the din of wearing a kippah. Rabbinical, Biblical, minhag, shtus, kabbalistic... then know the sugya if you "have" to wear a Kippah while learning. Then, if  a goy can even learn Torah. Then, if he will get an aveira if a goy doesn't wear the Kippah, or is it a mitzvah for the goy to wear the Kippah? Yada yada yada.... @DanWeisberg

Comment: @Moshe that's all fine yet my discussion with you so far concerns the meaning behind a Jew wearing a kippah. I received your comment regarding the source I brought up, so I consider this part of discussion finished:)

Comment: Kippah is a very "fun" sugya :)

Comment: @Moshe also, to be clear my question is based on a premise that just as it's halacha for a Jew to study Torah with his head covered, so is it recommended and praiseworthy for a goy to do so as well. As for whether a goy is allowed to study Torah, check my comments above and the source I brought up

Comment: @Moshe your comments helped me understand though that a goy is not required to cover his head when studying Torah

Comment: That's what awesome jews do. They help each other @DanWeisberg :)