# Does the law not to say G-d's name without a head covering apply to woman?

Tags: halacha, women, head-covering

Does the law not to say G-d's name without a head covering ( [Relationship between wearing a kippa and reciting a blessing](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14347/5120) ) apply to woman?

Source?
If not, why not?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/56273/759

Comment: Duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29417/759

Answer (score 0):

If the question is based on Shulchan Aruch 91:3 ( chabad.org/3299176/#v3), perhaps the answer can be found by understanding what's happening when a Jewish man covers his head:

The Chabad explanation involves a discussion of the 5 levels of the soul, and that covering the head reveals the 4th and potentially the 5th levels of the soul.

Applying this to women, maybe they are already revealing these levels?  They do this simply by being who they are?  Men, perhaps, need a little help in this regard?

That's how I understand it.  It's not a legal / Halachic opinion, but it's the best I have to offer.

Here's a link to the Chabad discussion about covering the head and the levels of the soul.

https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3102418/jewish/Why-Wear-Both-a-Kippah-and-a-Hat.htm